# Consultas DML con diferente rendimiento en servidores similares

Tags: mysql

Estoy midiendo el rendimiento entre dos servidores que montan MySQL 5.6. El servidor DB1 es un servidor dedicado y el servidor DB2 es un servidor que comparte recursos con otros servicios como HTTP, Redis y AMQP (por lo que tiene más carga de trabajo).

La idea es separar todos los servicios de DB2 en servidores dedicados. El problema viene con el rendimiento de los comando DML entre servidores. Ejecutando la misma consulta, el servidor compartido DB2 tiene un rendimiento superior (entre 400ms y 3500ms más rápido de media en todas las consultas) que el servidor dedicado. Son dos servidores que montan el mismo tipo de hardware, sistema operativo (CentOS 6) y la base de datos es idéntica (incluyendo índices).

DB1 dispone de 8 hilos y 32GB de RAM. La configuración my.cnf es la siguiente:

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

symbolic-links=0

# Recommended in standard MySQL setup
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES

# Fine Tuning
thread_stack = 512K
key_buffer = 1G
max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 12M
read_buffer_size = 12M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 6M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
query_cache_size = 512M
query_cache_type = 1
join_buffer_size = 16M
tmp_table_size = 512M
max_connections = 2048
max_heap_table_size = 64M
wait_timeout = 3000

skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

# InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 24G
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 256M
innodb_file_per_table = ON
innodb_log_buffer_size = 64M
innodb_log_file_size = 64M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

DB2 dispone de 16 hilos y 64GB de RAM. La configuración my.cnf es la siguiente:

```
[mysqld]
pid-file        = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
datadir         = /var/lib/mysql
log-error       = /var/log/mysql/error.log

symbolic-links=0

# Fine Tuning
thread_stack = 512K
key_buffer = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 32M
sort_buffer_size = 4M
read_buffer_size = 4M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 2M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_size = 128M
query_cache_type = 1
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 256M
max_connections = 800
max_heap_table_size = 32M
wait_timeout = 5000

skip-external-locking
skip-name-resolve

# InnoDB
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 5000
innodb_thread_concurrency = 8
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 40M
innodb_file_per_table=1

innodb_buffer_pool_size = 4G
innodb_log_buffer_size = 256M
innodb_log_file_size = 1G
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
```

¿Alguien que sepa qué puede estar sucediendo?

¡Muchas gracias!

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina. +1 por exponer tu problema de forma correcta. Saludos.